# How do you make components reusable across applications?

Tags: reactjs

For example, I have a grid component that takes a bunch of props (css class names, optional side and bottom components etc) to render items on a grid-type formation. It comes with a scss file that's responsible for main styling, and another scss file with variables to control things like size, media queries etc.

Currently I have tried putting the .js and .scss files into a separate folder, committing then pushing to github. Then pulling it into a new app. There has to be an easier way, right?

What should do I do 
1) assuming I would like to keep it private
2) if I don't mind publishing it for others to see?

Comment: 1) pushing into a private repo
2) publishing as a package on npm

Comment: I know and have tried both already. First doesn't seem optimal, second seems to make it public (and I may not want that).

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/private-modules/intro